# Sum javascript array based on timestamp

Tags: arrays, json

I have a 6 JSON with:
timestamp
value
from a power meter

I need to aggregrate the values in 15min timestamps.

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      [
        1616968800000,
        3159.1404000000007
      ],
      [
        1616968886400,
        1288.7799999999997
      ],
      [
        1616968972800,
        522.8924999999999
      ],
      [
        1616969059200,
        446.1015
      ],
      [
        1616969145600,
        2340.1559999999995
      ]
```

and so on...

When I aggregrate then I start with timestamp:
1616968800000

So I need to loop all other JSON arrays to get the values:
1616968800000 to 1616969700000

But when the timestamp is in the middle of 2 timestamps, he has to calculate the value based of the timespan.

It is to calculate a power meter.

Thank you!

Comment: Kindly show us the efforts that you have made in solving the problem at hand.

Comment: I'm not sure if this do, what I need:
https://github.com/djsauble/timeseries-aggregate
seems need node.js, which I have not installed

Answer (score 0):

so far I have no aggregation, because not sure how I can do.

I´m drawing a google chart and add the values with this:

```
function drawChart() {

  // 487 = Bezug
  // 486 = Lieferung
  // 504 = PV
  // 214 = Verbrauch
  var json_day = 'http://192.168.0.202:8080/db/getdata?id=dlc&eid=487,486,504,214&range=yesterday';
  var http_request_day = new XMLHttpRequest();
  try {
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari
    http_request_day = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } catch (e) {
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try {
      http_request_day = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");

    } catch (e) {

      try {
        http_request_day = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (e) {
        // Something went wrong
        alert("Your browser broke!");
        return false;
      }

    }
  }

  http_request_day.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (http_request_day.readyState == 4) {
      var data_line = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data_line.addColumn('date', 'Date');
      data_line.addColumn('number', 'Verbrauch');
      data_line.addColumn('number', 'PV');
      data_line.addColumn('number', 'Bezug');
      data_line.addColumn('number', 'Lieferung');     
      var jsonObj = JSON.parse(http_request_day.responseText);

      var rows = [];

    // Verbrauch
      for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.data[3].length; i++) {
        // console.log(i);
        var date = new Date(jsonObj.data[3][i][0]);
        var consumption = parseFloat(jsonObj.data[3][i][1]);
        date = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds(), date.getMilliseconds());
        dateNew = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
        
        var pv = 0;
        // search PV
        for (var ii = 0; ii < jsonObj.data[2].length; ii++) {
            var date = new Date(jsonObj.data[2][ii][0]);
            if ( jsonObj.data[2][ii][0] >= jsonObj.data[3][i][0]) {
                // console.log(i + "/" + ii);
                pv = parseFloat(jsonObj.data[2][ii][1]);
                break;
            }
        }
        
        var bezug = 0;
        // search Bezug
        for (var ii = 0; ii < jsonObj.data[0].length; ii++) {
            var date = new Date(jsonObj.data[0][ii][0]);
            if ( jsonObj.data[0][ii][0] >= jsonObj.data[3][i][0]) {
                // console.log(i + "/" + ii);
                bezug = parseFloat(jsonObj.data[0][ii][1]);
                break;
            }
        }
        
        var lieferung = 0;
        // search Lieferung
        for (var ii = 0; ii < jsonObj.data[1].length; ii++) {
            var date = new Date(jsonObj.data[1][ii][0]);
            if ( jsonObj.data[1][ii][0] >= jsonObj.data[3][i][0]) {
                // console.log(i + "/" + ii);
                lieferung = parseFloat(jsonObj.data[1][ii][1]) * -1;
                break;
            }
        }
        
        data_line.addRow([date, consumption, pv, bezug, lieferung]);

      }

      var optionsLine = {
        title: 'Energieverbrauch',
        animation: {
          duration: 1000,
          easing: 'out',
          startup: true
        },
        hAxis: {
          gridlines: {
            color: 'none'
          },
          gridThickness: 4,
          format: 'HH:MM',
          color: '#AAA',
          fontName: 'Arial',
          fontSize: '1'
        },
        interpolateNulls: true,
        backgroundColor: {
          fillOpacity: 0
        },
        legendTextStyle: {
          color: '#AAA'
        },
        titleTextStyle: {
          color: '#AAA'
        },
        series: {
          0: {
            color: '#0699fa',
            lineWidth: 1
          },
          1: {
            color: '#edd409',
            lineWidth: 1
          },
          2: {
            color: '#f1ca3a'
          },
          3: {
            color: '#6f9654'
          },
          4: {
            color: '#1c91c0'
          },
          5: {
            color: '#43459d'
          },
        },
        vAxis: {
          gridlines: {
            count: -1,
            color: 'none'
          },
          gridThickness: 4,
          format: '#,###W',
          color: '#AAA',
          fontName: 'Arial',
          fontSize: '5',
          minValue: 0
        },
        explorer: {
          actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'],
          axis: 'horizontal',
          keepInBounds: true,
          maxZoomIn: 4.0
        },
      };


      var container = document.getElementById('current');
      var chartArea = new google.visualization.AreaChart(container);
```

But here, I search for the next timestamp and added to the first ... this is not exact or correct.

I need to calc the power over 15min.
I want it for a 15min Intervall

Example2:
00:00, 5kW

00:15, 12kW

00:30, 12kW

Here is for the first 15min 5kW, for the second 12kW

00:00, 5kW

00:07, 10kw

00:15, 12kW

00:30, 12kW

Here is for the first 15min 7.7kW,

(5*(7*60) + 10*(8*60))/(15*60)

(2100 + 4800)/900 = 7.7kW

for the second 12kW

But I need to loop from timestamp to timestamp ... and calc the in the past and future, because which timestamp I found.